# Why won't columns sit side by side in Foundation 6?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

When my screen goes to 1090 px or in tablet mode the columns won't sit side by side (one of them is pushed down creating a white space in between). I am using Foundation 6 with 12 columns but it won't work on medium-sized screens. It works once it the desktop size is large.

```css
.white-no-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 0px;
}

.black-no-content {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
}

#left-about {
    background-color: #e6e3e3;
    height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!-- back white sections -->
<section class="row">
    <article class="columns medium-2 black-no-content">
    </article>
    <article class="columns medium-10 white-no-content">
    </article>
</section>

<!-- about -->
<section class="row">
    <article class="columns medium-2" id="left-about">   
    </article>
    <article class="columns medium-10 text-center">
        <div>
            <a href="#fashion-about">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Read the docs on the grid. I don't think you are using it correctly. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html. Keep in mind that the columns inherit up

Comment: Improved spelling, style, and formatted code into a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code into a codepen and it works (the columns are side-by-side even at 1090px and above): https://codepen.io/dgenest/pen/yXLNLq

1. Have you included the foundation CSS in your page?

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">
   ```
2. The default breakpoint for medium screens is 640px.  If your screen is smaller, you would see the columns stack.